# How to save fetched data from server to component state using redux and redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props, react-state

In my react app I have component named profile, and I am fetching data from server and showing it inside that component. I am using redux and redux-thunk along with axios. With help of mapDispatchToProps function, i am calling redux action for fetching that data when component is mounted and saving it to redux state. After that, using mapStateToProps function i am showing that data on the screen via props. That works fine. Now I want to have possibility to edit, for example, first name of that user. To accomplish that i need to save that data to component state when data is fetched from server, and then when text field is changed, component state also needs to be changed. Don't know how to save data to component sate, immediately after it is fetched.

Simplified code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getUserData: () => dispatch(userActions.getUserData())
    }
}    

class Profile extends Component {
    state:{
         user: {}
    }

    componentDidMount (){
        this.props.getUserData()
        // when data is saved to redux state i need to save it to component state
    }

    editTextField = () => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
       })
    };

    render(){

        const { user } = this.props;

        return(
            <TextField id="firstName"
                   value={user.firstName}
                   onChange={this.editTextField}
            />
        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` for that or give a callback function to your action.
I will show both.

First lets see `componentDidUpdate`,

Here you can compare your previous data and your present data, and if there is some change, you can set your state, for example if you data is an array.

`state = {
  data: []
}`

then inside your `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if(prevProps.data.length !== this.props.data.length) {
    // update your state, in your case you just need userData, so you 
    // can compare something like name or something else, but still 
    // for better equality check, you can use lodash, it will also check for objects, 
    this.setState({ data: this.props.data});
  }
}

_.isEqual(a, b); // returns false if different
```

This was one solution, another solution is to pass a call back funtion to your action,

lets say you call `this.props.getData()`

you can do something like this

```
this.props.getData((data) => {
 this.setState({ data });
})
```

here you pass your data from redux action to your state.

your redux action would be something like this.

```
export const getData = (done) => async dispatch => {
  const data = await getSomeData(); // or api call

  // when you dispatch your action, also call your done 
  done(data);
}
```

Comment: i think that first solution with componentDidUpdate won't work cause it will trigger only when stats changes, and i need to get it trigger when props changes

Comment: componentDidUpdate also runs when there is change in props :)

Comment: Happy to help, you can mark my answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React 16.0+, you can use the static method `getDerivedStateFromProps`. You can read about it [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

Using your example:

```
class Profile extends Component {
  // other methods here ...

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    return {
      user: props.user
    }
  }

  // other methods here...
}
```

Comment: that works nice... but i will changing state every time i put something in text field, so this will trigger every time i do that, it would be nice it it would trigger on first rendering